# setHintTextColor() in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-text-color

I have View in which there are two text boxes, and the user can select text color from another view on the same screen (through dialog box).

So when the user changes color via dialog box, I am changing color of `EditText` text and its hint. But when there is some text is available in `EditText` after that user selects other color, then that text is coming in that color. But if I remove all that text then the color of **HintText** is that of the previous color.

For example, currently if I have red color in text box and the user selects green color so text is there in green color. But if I remove that text then hint text are coming in red even if I **change hint color** in code. This problem only comes when there is some text there. if it is blank and hint  text is there then problem is not coming.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134463/edittext-unable-to-change-the-text-color/25134499#25134499

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use this to change the hint color. -

```
editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Solution for your problem -

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3){
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        if(arg0.toString().length() <= 0) //check if length is equal to zero
            tv.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why such a complicated solution which can be accomplished in half a line, as anandc answered below.

Comment: because that solution is not solving his problem?

Answer (score 319):

Simply add this in your `layout` for the `EditText` :

> android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"

Comment: How is this supposed to solve OP's question? the question is about how to change hint color DYNAMICALLY when the EditText has some text and I don't see how this will solve it...

Comment: Please read the question carefully. author has not asked in appropriate manner.

Answer (score 23):

Default Colors:

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
```

For Color code:

```
android:textColorHint="#33b5e5"
```

Comment: don't take these edits personally. Editing basically improves the readability of the answer and/or improve the completeness of it. Also, if applicable, add explanation about the code where needed, such as what is does or what problem the OP was facing, etc. :)

Answer (score 15):

Inside Layout Xml File We can Change Color of Hint.....

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/*****"
```

you can replace ***** with color or color code.

Answer (score 9):

Seems that [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) apply the hintTextColor only if the text is empty. So simple solution will be like this

```
Editable text = mEditText.getText();
mEditText.setText(null);
mEditText.setHintTextColor(color);
mEditText.setText(text);
```

If you have multiple fields, you can extend the EditText and write a method which executes this logic and use that method instead.

Answer (score 6):

Programmatically in Java - At least API v14+

`exampleEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));`

Comment: on my samsung S5 apiV19 the same trouble, as @dishan mentioned: `setHintTextColor(color)` not working in case there is some text, EVEN if it's `""`.

Answer (score 2):

This is like default hint color, worked for me:

`editText.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);`

Answer (score 0):

You could call `editText.invalidate()` after you reset the hint color. That could resolve your issue. Actually the SDK update the color in the same way.