# EditText unable to change the text color

Tags: android, android-edittext, textcolor

I;m trying to change text color in EditText like this

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/hint_user_name"
        android:textColor="#B49228FF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#B49228" />
```

but it doesn't change this color `#B49228` is gold it appears like this 
[image]

My Device : `HoneyWell Delphine 70e`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint** doesn't change color. Try typing text, it will work. As the color change is for text that you input.
And also your color code is incorrect, has extra **FF** for first EditText.

**Edited:**

Use the following to change hint color

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: you are correct man :)
it Slip inadvertently hhhhhh
I'm waiting to make it correct answer

Comment: yes the first answer is incorrect but after editing it's true :)
and both of your answer and @jaimin answer add knowledge for me 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hint color and Text Color are two different thing use this codes
create a **color.xml** file in **values** folder
then add  color #B49228  in it  like this `<color name="myColor">#B49228  </color>`
and use it like this

```
 android:textColor="@color/myColor"
```

and you are using hint text so to change hint color use this code

```
  android:textColorHint="@color/myColor"
```

Comment: `android:textColorHint="@color/myColor"`
this is new it work to change hint color @Nabin

Comment: the solution of this answer is so obvious. that it may have same answers

Comment: i think this is what you want @BlackRoot

Comment: It is now correct. He has now edited to be correct :-) So I too voted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
```

Please try.

Answer (score -1):

put in color.xml your color like

```
<color name="mytextColor">#B49228</color>
```

and use this

```
android:textColor="@color/mytextColor"
```

Comment: incorrect answer check @jaimin answer history 
this part jaimin add which make his answer correct 

****and you are using hint text so to change hint color use this code**

  `android:textColorHint="@color/myColor"`**