# cannot change edittext hint color

Tags: android, colors, edit, hint

I impement custom Edittext as below. my application hinttext color wont change in samsung galaxy neo and all hints hides in with this edit text. I try to change textHintColor in xml and also tried :

```
nameEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
```

but nothings changes just in this phone.

```
public class EditText extends android.widget.EditText {

    public EditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.APPLICATION_FONT);
        setTypeface(tf);
//        setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
    }

    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle);
        final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.APPLICATION_FONT);
        setTypeface(tf);
//        setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
    }

    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.APPLICATION_FONT);
        setTypeface(tf);
//        setTextSize(this.getTextSize());
    }
```

I also change app theme but nothings changes.
and this is usage of edittext:

```
  <com.myproj.widget.EditText
                    style="@style/Text.SettingItem"
                    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134463/edittext-unable-to-change-the-text-color#answer-25134499

Answer (score 6):

Simply add this to the layout of EditText:

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" // any color
```

or You can set color from color res file

```
android:textColorHint="@color/red"
```

Comment: can you post your xml code here.. // delete all the code from java side and add this line in xml only.. it should work.. i have tested it now. it's working..

Comment: I updated question but i know that it should work but it seems something override my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
```

change your colorAccent to your desired color inside your Theme,this will change your EditText line,Cursor as well as your hint

or you can also include this style inside your style.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

then inside your TextInputLayout you can put it like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/password"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textWebPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

have yuo declare background in your xml?i have a similar question,the answer is wrongsize background,you can delete it to test