# Android: Setting EditText's default hint color from .java

Tags: android, hint

So I have a LinearLayout and 4 EditText-s in it with grayish hint colors in XML. And I have button that dynamically adds new EditText-s to LinearLayout. The problem is when I use setHint("text") it makes hint color for new created views black.

Also tried setHintTextColor() but the only way it worked for me by setting custom color. Is there a default hint color that I can set by setHintTextColor()?? or maybe some method that does it when it's called?

Code looks like this:

```
private EditText createNewTextView(String text) {
    ++x;
    final ActionBar.LayoutParams lparams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    editText.setHint("Name" + x);
    editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hintcolor));
    return editText;
}
```

p.s. I made new color in colors which is called hintcolor

I've been looking for solution, but there was nothing that would help me, or I just didn't understood it. I'm new at android and programming so don't judge please, just explain. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438478/sethinttextcolor-in-edittext Have you took a look at this post ?

Comment: tried it but it says cannot resolve "white", maybe adding it to colors would help, but I still would need right color code

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but for the sake of others who have the same problem, I solved it by making a method to get default **textColorHint**.
It returns the color of the hint text for all the states (disabled, focussed, selected...) that specified in the current theme.

```java
int getHintTextColor(Context context) {
    int[] hintTextColor = new int[] { android.R.attr.textColorHint };
    int indexOfAttrTextColorHint = 0;
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(hintTextColor);
    int textColor = ta.getColor(indexOfAttrTextColorHint, 0xFF808080);
    ta.recycle();
    return textColor;
}
```

I hope this helps.